# UTF-8 encoding for subject in contact form email

Tags: php, utf-8, contact-form

On this sites [Website Link](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/kontakt.php) contact form I need to send the subject for email in UTF-8.
Where in the code we need to do declare the UTF-8 encoding?

kontakt.php:

```
<?
require_once "php/sendmail.class.php";
$sendmail = new sendMail();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
$sendmail->setParams($_POST);
$sendmail->parseBody();
$sendmail->setHeaders();
if ($sendmail->send())
{
    header('Location: kontakt.php?success=1');
}
}
?>
```

sendmail.class.php:

```
class sendMail {

var $to      = 'email'; // set contact email

var $name    = '';
var $subject = '';
var $email   = '';
var $body    = '';
var $error   = array();
var $headers = array();

function setHeaders()
{
    $this->headers = "From: $this->email\r\n";
    $this->headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $this->headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
}

function parseBody()
{
    $message     = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
    $message .= '<tr style="background-color: #eee;"><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>' . $this->name . '</td></tr>';
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>E-Mail-Adresse:</strong> </td><td>" . $this->email . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Betreff:</strong> </td><td>" . $this->subject . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Text:</strong> </td><td>" . $this->body . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";
    $this->body  = $message;
}

function send()
{
    if ($this->error)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (mail($this->to, $this->subject, $this->body, $this->headers))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->error[] = 'Fehler beim senden';
        return FALSE;
    }
```

In the subject I need the utf 8 german characters encoding. Where do we need to declare it in the code? For the message I found out what to do but for the subject I found no solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

here is how i did it:

```
$head = "From: \"=?ISO-8859-15?Q?".imap_8bit("äöüßÄÖÜ sollte hier gehen")."?=\" <info@mydomain.de>\n";
$subject = "=?ISO-8859-15?Q?".imap_8bit("äöüßÄÖÜ sollte hier gehen")."?=";
mail($mail,$subject,$text,$head);
```

that is ofc just Latin-15 (German) encoding. utf-8 works the same way:
look here for a great explanation on how to use character encoding in mail headers:
http://ncona.com/2011/06/using-utf-8-characters-on-an-e-mail-subject/

for your code you have to change this in the sendmail class:

```
if (mail($this->to, '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($this->subject).'?=', $this->body, $this->headers))
```

! this only works properly if your php file is utf-8 encoded !

still very annoying. then i switched to [phpmailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/). that does everything for you. way more easy. i would suggest you use that.

Comment: Can you tell me where to integrate it in my code? I'm getting error messages.

Comment: var $subject = '=?utf-8?q?' . imab_8bit( $subject ) . '?='; gives me: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in /mnt/web3/a2/69/53523169/htdocs/php/sendmail.class.php on line 8

Comment: look at my edit. make sure the php file is utf8 encoded, also for further information look at the link http://ncona.com/2011/06/using-utf-8-characters-on-an-e-mail-subject/ .its well explained there how it works

Answer (score 0):

Or you can replace a $this->subject variable with

> $this->subject = '=?windows-1251?B?'.base64_encode($this->subject).'?=';

Just replace

> windows-1251

with some other encoding ( utf-8 or something else )